# udacity-sunshine app crashes even after using ASyncTask

Tags: android

```
//this is the ForecastFragment file

package com.example.sumanth.sunshine1.app;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

    public ForecastFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        String[] forecastArray={
                "Mon 6/23 - Sunny - 31/17",
                 "Tue 6/24 - Foggy - 21/8",
                 "Wed 6/25 - Cloudy - 22/17",
                 "Thurs 6/26 - Rainy - 18/11",
                "Fri 6/27 - Foggy - 21/10",
                "Sat 6/28 - TRAPPED IN WEATHERSTATION - 23/18",
                "Sun 6/29 - Sunny - 20/7"
                                   };
                  List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));



        ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
                weekForecast

        );

        ListView listView=(ListView)
```

rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);

```
        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

        return  rootView;

    }
```

the app works fine till this section.but later after inserting the networking code it doesn't open(crashes)
       //this is the fetchweathertask class,even after moving the networking code from the above class the app still fails to launch on the phone

```
    public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

                private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();

                        @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
                                // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
                            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
                            BufferedReader reader = null;

// Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
                            String forecastJsonStr = null;

                            try {
                                // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
                                // Possible parameters are available at OWM's forecast API page, at
                                // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
                                URL url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7");

                                // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
                                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                                urlConnection.connect();

                                // Read the input stream into a String
                                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                                if (inputStream == null) {
                                    // Nothing to do.
                                    forecastJsonStr = null;
                                }
                                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                                String line;
                                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                    // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                                    // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                                    // buffer for debugging.
                                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                                }

                                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                                    forecastJsonStr = null;
                                }
                                forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error ", e);
                                // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attempting
                                // to parse it.
                                forecastJsonStr = null;
                            } finally{
                                if (urlConnection != null) {
                                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                                }
                                if (reader != null) {
                                    try {
                                        reader.close();
                                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                                        Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        return null;
                    }
    }
}
```

Comment: new to stackoverflow.kindly oblige the format of the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the Internet permission in your manifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Without it, your app will crash.

Read this https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

I tested your code without the permission and it crashes. I also tested it with the permission and it doesn't crash. Start with that.

You still have other things to do, like include the API key in your url string. Remember you can post on the Udacity forums where hundreds of students are working on this same project right now.